# Not able to Create New Azure Storage when creating Web App Bot

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-storage

I've just started playing with Microsoft Azure. My intention is to create a Cortana Skill.

For the same, I'm trying to create a Web App Bot. But in the form that one has to fill, to create a Web App Bot, I'm not able to Create New Azure Storage or Use Existing.

It's giving me a `Not Available` error message for any name I type in case of a *Create New*. And I don't have any Existing Azure Storage so I can't select that option.

I'm not really sure if I'm doing something wrong here. But I'm not able to complete the form and click Create as there's an error on the form.

What do I do? Following are the value of the fields in the form:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd guess you already have this name - did you try "Select Existing"?

Comment: No. It's actually the first time that I'm creating a Bot.

Comment: Try what alan suggested below - make the storage separately and then select existing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue by Selecting `Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN` in my `Subscription` Field.

Apparently, the DreamSpark Subscription is limited and doesn't allow/limits creation/consumption of resources on Azure.

[image]

Comment: It would be nice if there were more descriptive errors.

Comment: Well, everything was added as a part of the screenshots that I attached. Not sure what else was expected. It isn't like there was a console error or something that I had to post.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try again and see if you still see the same problem

I tried to mimic your behaviour, but it seems ok

[image]

Another way is try create an Azure Storage first ([Link](https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.StorageAccount-ARM)), then chose from `Select Existing`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Although it didn't really help to fix the issue. But I really  appreciate your efforts.